# How do I print out just the word itself in a WordNet synset using Python NLTK?

Tags: python, regex, nltk, wordnet

Is there a way in Python 2.7 using `NLTK` to just get the word and not the extra formatting that includes `"synset"` and the parentheses and the `"n.01"` etc?

For instance if I do

```
        wn.synsets('dog')
```

My results look like:

```
[Synset('dog.n.01'), Synset('frump.n.01'), Synset('dog.n.03'), Synset('cad.n.01'), Synset('frank.n.02'), Synset('pawl.n.01'), Synset('andiron.n.01'), Synset('chase.v.01')]
```

How can I instead get a list like this?

```
dog
frump
cad
frank
pawl
andiron
chase
```

Is there a way to do this using `NLTK` or do I have to use `regular expressions`? Can I use `regular expressions` within a python script?

Comment: As per rule `includes "synset" and the parentheses and the "n.01"` `frank` and `chase` should not be part of the desired output?

Comment: unrelated to the question but `frank` is a synonym/shorthand for `frankfurter` which is a synonym for `hot dog` or `dog`.  Similarly `dog` as a verb means to `chase`.

Comment: I see a faintly ironic failure to meet subtly ironic hues...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this without regular expressions, you can use a list comprehension.

```
[synset.name.split('.')[0] for synset in wn.synsets('dog') ]
```

What you're doing here is saying that, for each synset return the first word before the period.

Comment: Make sure to use name() instead of name, NLTK has changed this function slightly.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for synset in wn.synsets('dog'):
    print synset.lemmas[0].name
```

You want to iterate over each synset for dog, and then print out the headword of the synset.  Keep in mind that multiple words could attach to the same synset, so if you want to get all the words associated with all the synsets for dog, you could do:

```
for synset in wn.synsets('dog'):
    for lemma in synset.lemmas:
        print lemma.name
```

Comment: Alas, the first snipped throws `'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable` and the second snippet throws `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable` with NLTK 3.0

Comment: @duhaime What were previously attributes have become methods. YOu need to do `synset.lemmas()[0].name()`

Answer (score 3):

aelfric5578 you're close: attribute name is a function, not a string.
`[synset.name().split('.')[0] for synset in wn.synsets('dog') ]`

Answer (score 0):

Using lemma name might work but there is a canonical variable for the synset name for the `Synset` object, try:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synset('dog.n.1')
Synset('dog.n.01')
>>> wn.synset('dog.n.1').name
'dog.n.01'
>>> wn.synset('dog.n.1').name.partition('.')[0]
'dog'
>>> for ss in wn.synsets('dog'):
...     print ss.name.partition('.')[0]
... 
dog
frump
dog
cad
frank
pawl
andiron
chase
```

Comment: do you happen to know if a similar method is available in NLTK 3.0? I'm getting an error running the partition line `'function' object has no attribute 'partition'`

Comment: @duhaime, use `wn.synset('dog.n.1').name()` because NLTK changed Synset properties to get functions instead. see https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

**it is very simple just create a list and then get the first value**

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
syn=[]
for s in wn.synsets('dog'):
   syn.appned(s)
return syn[0]
```