# Extract Word from Synset using Wordnet in NLTK 3.0

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

Some time ago, someone on SO asked [how to retrieve a list of words for a given synset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664250/how-do-i-print-out-just-the-word-itself-in-a-wordnet-synset-using-python-nltk) using NLTK's wordnet wrapper. Here is one of the suggested responses:

```
for synset in wn.synsets('dog'):
    print synset.lemmas[0].name
```

Running this code with NLTK 3.0 yields `TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable`.

I tried each of the previously-proposed solutions (each of the solutions described on the page linked above), but each throws an error. I therefore wanted to ask: Is it possible to print the words for a list of synsets with NLTK 3.0? I would be thankful for any advice others can offer on this question.

Comment: Is there a reason for using the latest NLTK versus more stable (albeit earlier) version?

Comment: I'm working in multilingual contexts, and I thought the Open Multilingual Wordnet was only implemented in 3.0. If it was available in earlier iterations, though, I'm all ears!

Comment: It looks like OMW has been available via NLTK for some time now. I'll try reverting to an earlier and more stable release...

Comment: Could you show where your attempts fail, e.g. what you tried and the errors/complaints?

Comment: The specific error message and a MWE would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, edited question with error. If you take a peek at the page to which I linked, you'll see I commented the errors NLTK 3.0 throws for those solutions as well...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

WordNet works fine in NLTK 3.0. You are just accessing the lemmas (and names) in the wrong way. Try this instead:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.__version__
'3.0.0'
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> for synset in wn.synsets('dog'):
    for lemma in synset.lemmas():
        print lemma.name()


dog
domestic_dog
Canis_familiaris
frump
dog
dog
cad
bounder
blackguard
...
```

`synset.lemmas` is a method and does not have a `__getitem__()` method (and so is not subscriptable).

Comment: I am getting error at this syntax : 
nltk.__version__'3.0.0' My NLTK version is 3.2.1, I tried nltk.__version__
'3.2.1'. But getting error.

Answer (score 10):

You can also go directly to the lemma names with `lemma_names()`:

```python
>>> wordnet.synset('dog.n.1').lemma_names()
['dog', 'domestic_dog', 'Canis_familiaris']
```

And it works for multiple languages

```python
>>>> wordnet.synset('dog.n.1').lemma_names(lang='jpn')
['イヌ', 'ドッグ', '洋犬', '犬', '飼犬', '飼い犬']
```

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
wn.synset('dog.n.1').name()
```

instead of:

```
wn.synset('dog.n.1').name
```

because NLTK changed Synset properties to get functions instead. see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/ba8ab7e23ea2b8d61029484098fd62d5986acd9c

This is a good list of changes to NLTK's API to suit py3.x: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Porting-your-code-to-NLTK-3.0