# How to solve iteration issue on data set in Python when using WordNet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I try to use **wordnet** in **python** to list some of **synonyms** of a (word)
I have the following code:

```
for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('dog')):
  print "Meaning",i, "NLTK ID:", j.name
  print "Definition:",j.definition
  print "Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names)
  print
```

**I use Python 2.7.10**
and I got the following error :

```
print "Synonyms:", ", ".join((j.lemma_names))
  TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

How could I solve this issue ?

Comment: What is the output of `type(j.lemma_names)`?

Comment: the output is <type 'instancemethod'>

Comment: you probably have to call it using a language argument (ISO codes). Like `j.lemma_names('eng')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Word from Synset using Wordnet in NLTK 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517924/extract-word-from-synset-using-wordnet-in-nltk-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`lemma_names`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset.lemma_names) is a method - you should call it in order to retrieve names:

```
print "Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names())
#                                         ^^
```

Comment: why they stop my account ?

Comment: @JohnKanti, who stopped and where?