# How can I print out the main lemma of a WordNet synset? Python NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have a large set of WordNet synsets. A small portion of this set is:

```
syns = {"Synset('brutal.s.04')", "Synset('benignant.s.02')"}
```

I want to print out the synset term (the main lemma of the synset) for each synset in the set. For example, the output of the above set should be:

```
brutal, benignant
```

This is the code I used:

```
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
    for s in syns:
        print(wn.s.lemmas[0])
```

but this does not work, because s is considered a string, and not an object. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 's'
```

This is because s is seen as a string, and not as an object. I tried to change s to byte form like so:

```
    s = bytes(s)
```

But that does not work. How can I print out only the lemma as mentioned above, in the simplest way?

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664250/how-do-i-print-out-just-the-word-itself-in-a-wordnet-synset-using-python-nltk), and this is a good way to do it, but my set of synsets are in string form, and not actually objects.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: So your data is a list of strings that look like this: "Synset('brutal.s.04')" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
>>> syns = {"Synset('brutal.s.04')", "Synset('benignant.s.02')"}
>>> [wn.synset(i[8:-2]) for i in syns]
[Synset('benignant.s.02'), Synset('brutal.s.04')]
>>> syns = [wn.synset(i[8:-2]) for i in syns]
>>> syns[0].lemma_names()
[u'benignant', u'gracious']
```

---

Firstly to get an input with the type printed out in strings is weird. So the first intuitive approach would be do something like `ast.literal_eval()` or `eval()` with the Synset type, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L305 (but before that see http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html):

```
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet import Synset
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> syns = {"Synset('brutal.s.04')", "Synset('benignant.s.02')"}
>>> [eval(i) for i in syns]
[Synset('None'), Synset('None')]
```

Apparently, `Synset` class won't work independent of the `nltk.corpus.wordnet`. So we take a look at the `wordnet.synset()` function instead (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1217). It seems like it only takes the pre-assigned name of a `Synset` object, so:

```
>>> wn.synset('brutal.s.04')
Synset('brutal.s.04')
>>> type(wn.synset('brutal.s.04'))
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset'>
```

And after which when the pseudo string synset in your input `syns` becomes a Synset, you can easily control the Synset as what is shown [How do I print out just the word itself in a WordNet synset using Python NLTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664250/how-do-i-print-out-just-the-word-itself-in-a-wordnet-synset-using-python-nltk)

Back to your weird input `syns`, doing the following will give me the  name of the synset:

```
>>> syns = {"Synset('brutal.s.04')", "Synset('benignant.s.02')"}
>>> list(syns)[0]
"Synset('benignant.s.02')"
>>> list(syns)[0][8:-2]
'benignant.s.02'
```

So back to converting it into a Synset:

```
>>> syns = {"Synset('brutal.s.04')", "Synset('benignant.s.02')"}
>>> [wn.synset(i[8:-2]) for i in syns]
[Synset('benignant.s.02'), Synset('brutal.s.04')]
>>> syns = [wn.synset(i[8:-2]) for i in syns]
>>> syns[0].lemma_names()
[u'benignant', u'gracious']
```

---

But let's roll back altogether, you're getting a weird input `syns` because someone has saved their output by simply casting a `str()` to a Synset object:

```
>>> syns[0]
Synset('benignant.s.02')
>>> str(syns[0])
"Synset('benignant.s.02')"
```

The person could have simply done:

```
>>> syns[0].name()
u'benignant.s.02'
```

Which then your input `syns` object will look like this:

```
syns = {u'brutal.s.04', u'benignant.s.02'}
```

and to read it, you can simply do:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> syns = {u'brutal.s.04', u'benignant.s.02'}
>>> syns = [wn.synset(i) for i in syns]
>>> syns[0]
Synset('brutal.s.04')
>>> syns[0].lemma_names()
[u'brutal']
```

Comment: +1. This is EXACTLY what I was hoping for. That is, to convert the string into the actual synset object, and THEN to get the synset term. I was actually hoping you would answer this, and was waiting for that yesterday. Thank you for this. @alvas

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your data correctly, you can just iterate over the list of strings and use regex to parse them.

```
import re
synsnew=[]
for word in syns:
    try:
        synsnew.append(re.search(r"'(\w+)\.",word).group(1))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' @Charlie Haley

Comment: That would imply that some of your data is of a different format or has no word in the same location.

Comment: I used the following: syns=[re.search(r"'(\w+)\.", word) for word in syns]         This is with no group. It works, but the output is like: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 15), match="'smooth.">. How can I print only the match, like in this case, the output should only be 'smooth' @Charlie Haley

Comment: What I mean is: do some of your synsets not have a lemma? Or do some have a different format?

Comment: They are all in one consistent format. Just as above. @Charlie Haley

Comment: Your error message implies that the regex came back with None, which would mean that there was an item without any occurrence of the pattern shown in both of your examples, with a lemma between a single quote and a period.

Comment: This may be the problem: "Synset('go-to-meeting.s.01')". How can I get around this? @Charlie Haley

Comment: It definitely does. This passes dashed terms.